# Workarounds for PHP's array_reduce integer third parameter

Tags: php, array-reduce

For [some](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45700) or [other](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=42566) reason, the [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) function in PHP only accepts integers as it's third parameter. This third parameter is used as a starting point in the whole reduction process:

```
function int_reduc($return, $extra) {
    return $return + $extra;
}

$arr = array(10, 20, 30, 40);
echo array_reduce($arr, 'int_reduc', 0); //Will output 100, which is 0 + 10 + 20 + 30 + 40

function str_reduc($return, $extra) {
    return $return .= ', ' . $extra;
}

$arr = array('Two', 'Three', 'Four');
echo array_reduce($arr, 'str_reduc', 'One'); //Will output 0, Two, Three, Four
```

In the second call, the `'One'` gets converted to it's integer value, which is 0, and then used.

**Why does PHP do this!?**

Any workarounds welcome...

Comment: Write your own function. Wrap everything PHP exposes. It's inconsistent as hell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't pass the `$initial` value, PHP assumes it is `NULL` and will pass `NULL` to your function. So a possible workaround is to check for `NULL` in your code:

```
function wrapper($a, $b) {
    if ($a === null) {
        $a = "One";
    }
    return str_reduc($a, $b);
}

$arr = array('Two', 'Three', 'Four');
echo array_reduce($arr, 'wrapper');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write your own array_reduce function. Here's one I bashed out quickly:

```
function my_array_reduce($input, $function, $initial=null) {
  $reduced = ($initial===null) ? $initial : array_shift($input);
  foreach($input as $i) {
    $reduced = $function($reduced, $i);
  }
  return $reduced;
}
```

Comment: Whoops - if you don't supply a third parameter, this might not work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The third parameter is optional

> **mixed** array_reduce  ( array $input  , callback $function  *[, int $initial  ]* )

see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php

just use:

```
$arr = array('One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four');
echo array_reduce($arr, 'str_reduc');
```

if you don't want the leading comma, use

```
function str_reduc($return, $extra) {
    if (empty($return))
        return $extra;
    return $return .= ', ' . $extra;
}
```

of course, if all you want to do is join the strings with a comma, use implode

```
echo implode(", ", $arr);
```

see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: The reaon I want to use the function isn't quite clear in my examples. It's quite complicated, BUT I need the third parameter.